# Touches are getting noticed twice in objective c

Tags: objective-c, session, nsnotificationcenter

I am implementing session inactivity for my app so that if user is inactive for 30 seconds, then show him a new uiviewcontroller as a formsheet. For touch event, i am using this code

```
(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [super sendEvent:event];
  // Only want to reset the timer on a Began touch or an Ended touch, to reduce the number of timer resets.
  NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
  if ([allTouches count] > 0) {
    // allTouches count only ever seems to be 1, so anyObject works here.
    UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
    if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan || phase == UITouchPhaseEnded) {
      [[BCDTimeManager sharedTimerInstance]resetIdleTimer];
    }
  }
}
```

In BCDTimeManager class which is a singleton class i have implemented resetIdleTimer and idleTimerExceed method

```
#import "BCDTimeManager.h"

@implementation BCDTimeManager

__strong static BCDTimeManager *sharedTimerInstance = nil;

NSTimer *idleTimer;
NSTimeInterval timeinterval;
+ (BCDTimeManager*)sharedTimerInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t predicate = 0;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        sharedTimerInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        NSString *timeout = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"session_timeout_preference"];
        timeinterval = [timeout doubleValue];

    });
    return sharedTimerInstance;
}

- (void)resetIdleTimer {
    if (idleTimer) {
        [idleTimer invalidate];
    }

    idleTimer = nil;
    NSLog(@"timeout is %ld",(long)timeinterval);
    idleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeinterval target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:true];
}

- (void)idleTimerExceeded {
    NSLog(@"idle time exceeded");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"ApplicationTimeout" object:nil];
}
```

But when i do any touch on the screens, in console, i can see NSLog is printed twice which is causing my NSNOtification action to be triggered twice.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. Please help me to figure out this.

Comment: Where are you defining ```idleTimer``` in ```resetIdleTimer```? It seems to me that it doesn't exist when you call ```[idleTimer invalidate]```.

Comment: I have updated the code to show where i am defining idleTimer

Comment: One things is i am adding NSNotification observer in rootViewController and removing the observer when user logs out. Is it possible that observers are not removed properly and causing notification to be added twice.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Code is doing right. I am seeing NSLog twice because of two touch event one touch began and one touch ended. So, this code is correct without any issue. Something is wrong with observers add or remove method. I will look into that